Strange timeout with ruby net/http
I am trying to download this file with ruby:
https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/ReadMe.txt
Here is a sample program, showing the issue (the comment shows what I get):
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'pp'

url = 'https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/ReadMe.txt'
uri = URI.parse(url)

begin
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.start
  p http.get(uri.path)
  http.finish
rescue => ex
  puts "error: #{ex.message} (#{ex.class})"
  # error: Failed to open TCP connection to evs.nci.nih.gov:443 (Blocking operation timed out!) (IO::TimeoutError)
end

I tried to understand where the problem stands, and found it is due to this:
begin
  p TCPSocket.new("evs.nci.nih.gov", 443, connect_timeout: 90)
rescue => ex
  puts "error: #{ex.message} (#{ex.class})"
  # error: Blocking operation timed out! (IO::TimeoutError)
end

I tried to get more information like this:
pp Addrinfo.getaddrinfo("evs.nci.nih.gov", 443)
# [#<Addrinfo: [2600:1f18:2102:3600:b4de:3448:7a8c:7ecd]:443 (evs.nci.nih.gov)>,
#  #<Addrinfo: [2600:1f18:2102:3601:4147:d992:65b4:4ac1]:443 (evs.nci.nih.gov)>,
#  #<Addrinfo: 52.1.83.88:443 (evs.nci.nih.gov)>,
#  #<Addrinfo: 3.224.99.192:443 (evs.nci.nih.gov)>]

Now this works:
p TCPSocket.new("3.224.99.192", 443, connect_timeout: 90)
# #<TCPSocket:fd 3, AF_INET, 192.168.1.25, 2433>

Ok, then let's try that:
url = 'https://3.224.99.192/ftp1/CDISC/ReadMe.txt'
uri = URI.parse(url)

begin
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.start
  p http.get(uri.path)
  http.finish
rescue => ex
  puts "error: #{ex.message} (#{ex.class})"
  # error: hostname "3.224.99.192" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
end

Yeah, I can figure that out.
I tried curl:
curl -o "ReadMe.txt" --trace-ascii "curl.log" "https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/ReadMe.txt"

It works like a charm.
Here is the log:
== Info:   Trying [2600:1f18:2102:3601:4147:d992:65b4:4ac1]:443...
== Info:   Trying 3.224.99.192:443...
== Info: Connected to evs.nci.nih.gov (3.224.99.192) port 443
== Info: schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
== Info: ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
== Info: ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
== Info: using HTTP/1.1
=> Send header, 99 bytes (0x63)
0000: GET /ftp1/CDISC/ReadMe.txt HTTP/1.1
0025: Host: evs.nci.nih.gov
003c: User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
0054: Accept: */*
0061: 
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Sat, 20 Apr 2024 16:27:02 GMT
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: Content-Type: text/plain
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Content-Length: 2157
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 30 bytes (0x1e)
0000: Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix)
<= Recv header, 46 bytes (0x2e)
0000: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
<= Recv header, 46 bytes (0x2e)
0000: Last-Modified: Fri, 29 Mar 2024 04:31:09 GMT
<= Recv header, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: ETag: "86d-614c51be679a1"
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Accept-Ranges: bytes
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 2157 bytes (0x86d)
0000: March 29, 2024.
(...)
086b: SC
== Info: Connection #0 to host evs.nci.nih.gov left intact

Any idea what goes wrong with ruby?

I found the reason: the issue is in Net::HTTP#connect, where you find this code:
s = Timeout.timeout(@open_timeout, Net::OpenTimeout) {
  begin
    TCPSocket.open(conn_addr, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)
  rescue => e
    raise e, "Failed to open TCP connection to " +
      "#{conn_addr}:#{conn_port} (#{e.message})"
  end
}

Timeout.timeout is notoriously flawed, and this code just does not work: even if you specify a timeout of 1 second, TCPSocket.open will wait on my machine 21 seconds to end with Blocking operation timed out! (IO::TimeoutError).
If you patch the code with Socket.tcp instead, it works:
    begin
      s = Socket.tcp(conn_addr, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port, connect_timeout: @open_timeout)
    rescue => e
      raise e, "Failed to open TCP connection to #{conn_addr}:#{conn_port} (#{e.message})"
    end

Now if you look into the implementation of Socket.tcp, you will see that it loops over the addresses returned by Addrinfo.getaddrinfo, trying to connect to them one by one until finding an address that works. Since in my case, the IPv6 addresses are returned first, it has to fail 2 times before connecting.
The best solution is therefore for me to specify an IPv4 address:
url = 'https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/ReadMe.txt'
uri = URI.parse(url)

address =
  Addrinfo.getaddrinfo(uri.host, nil)
  .sort_by { |a| a.ipv4? ? 0 : 1 }
  .first.ip_address
 
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true, ipaddr: address) do |http|
  # ...
end

Hope this will help someone.
Cheers

Feels almost certainly like an SSL/HTTPS problem, where your Ruby code does not have access to a certificate needed for the communication. (Perhaps this is obvious to you.)

Thank you, but no: the issue is that ruby tries only the first of the IP addresses, an IPv6 one, and gives up completely after 21 seconds, not trying the other addresses. I discovered that if I tell ruby to use an IPv4 address, everything works fine. This seems to be related to this: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15773 (rejected T_T).

I have the same problem with ruby net/http when using faraday to create a small script and it just all timeout. I use other language like Golang or curl then they both work properly. In your case, as you get the file via ip address but didn't specify the hostname so you have ssl certificate mismatch issue. The issue you mentioned by above comment on ruby bug list was well described so it just the problem of net/http fails to try another ip address after very long timeout. There's another discussion on timeout
